# SpringDoc Open API MVC Starter not showing fields of class annotated with Lombok @Data?

Tags: java, spring, lombok, springdoc

I have setup a new Spring Boot 3 project with the OpenAPI starter dependency

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

With the following class annotated with @Data

```java
@Data
public class SearchRequestDto {

    private String make;
    private String model;
    private String trim;
}
```

However when viewing the Swagger UI it shows the schema of this request as being empty.

Assuming it was an issue with reflection, I added my own getters/setters manually and it showed the properties of the class on Swagger UI.

[image]

How can I configure Spring OpenAPI to use the generated Lombok classes?

Googling only results in code generation (OpenAPI spec --> Java POJO) for example [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/324#issuecomment-785438335)

I have the Lombok annotation processor correctly configured in the Maven compiler plugin

Comment: Do you had set lombok fluent accessors to true?

Answer (score 0):

When using SpringDoc OpenApi, it relies on conventional getter and setter methods to determine the class fields to expose. However, when employing Lombok's fluent accessors, an issue may arise. This is because Lombok's fluent accessors generate getter and setter methods without the usual get and set prefixes that SpringDoc expects.

To resolve this, you can disable Lombok's fluent accessors for a specific class by using the @Accessors annotation and setting the fluent attribute to false. Here's an example:

Example:

```
@Data
@Accessors(fluent = false)
public class SearchRequestDto {
  ...
}
```

By applying @Accessors(fluent = false) to the class, you ensure that Lombok does not generate fluent accessor methods for it, thereby aligning with SpringDoc's requirements.

For more information on Lombok's fluent accessors, you can refer to the Lombok [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors).

By the time I wrote this post the Accessor was still an experimental feature.

Other way, if possible for your case, it's convert the class to a record.